# What is this red mushroom with the "inverted" cap?

Tags: species-identification, mycology

Picture taken on 29 March 2020, Czech Republic (Middle Europe). The cap is red, and its shape is "inverted". It is quite tough, first I thought it was a piece of plastic, but apparently it is growing from the ground.

What is the mushroom - if it is a mushroom :) ?

[image]

Answer (score 11):

Looks like [***Sarcoscypha Austriaca***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sarcoscypha_austriaca) (**scarlet elfcup**). It's actually used in many textbooks as a representative species for the [Ascomycetes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ascomycota).

Details from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sarcoscypha_austriaca) and [Messiah.edu](https://www.messiah.edu/Oakes/fungi_on_wood/cup%20and%20saucer/species%20pages/Sarcoscypha%20austriaca.htm) both confirm that this species is found in Europe and that it is typically found either as solitary or clustered fruiting bodies (2-5 cm wide) growing among rotting wood matter in damp wooded floors in the spring.

Photos below:

[image]

<sup>Source: [Wikimedia](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Sarcoscypha_austriaca_5.jpg)</sup>

[image]

<sup>Credit: William Roody; Source: [Messiah.edu](https://www.messiah.edu/Oakes/fungi_on_wood/cup%20and%20saucer/species%20pages/Sarcoscypha%20austriaca.htm)</sup>

Read more at [MushroomExpert.com](https://www.mushroomexpert.com/sarcoscypha_austriaca.html).